# Javascript not show input field on append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have simple input field like:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  {{ Form::label('stock', 'Stock') }}
  <input type="text" value="" class="stock form-control" name="stock" disabled>
</div>
```

And also I have JavaScript code which is working fine in back end and result is success `200`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='product_id']").on("change", function() {
      var productID = $(this).val();
      if(productID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url("admin/getProductInfo") }}/"+encodeURI(productID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $(".stock").empty().append("<input type='text' value='' class='form-control stock' name='stock' disabled>");
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $(".stock").append("<input type='text' class='form-control stock' value="value['stock']" name='stock' disabled>");
            });
        }
      }); //ajax
      }else{
        $(".stock").empty().append("<input type='text' value='' class='form-control stock' name='stock' disabled>");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

> My problem is that `append` on success will not replace with my static
>   input.

same code goes when I use on select and it works but somehow it doesn't work for inputs.

Comment: Check developer console for errors

Comment: You are trying to `append` `input` to an `input`??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i don't know man! i want replace it :)

Comment: You want to `replace` the `input` or its `value`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao both works for me.

Comment: @elegant-user https://ibb.co/hoXn1H

Comment: Then you can just do `$(".stock").val(value['stock'])`

Comment: But am confused why you are doing `$.each`?

Comment: output will be `<input value="" class="stock form-control" name="stock" disabled="" type="text">` however it shows result but not get it into value.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao each is because my product data comes in array

Comment: Am bit getting lost here.. Can you show us the sample response from `ajax call` and what's the expected behavior?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao https://ibb.co/fSgfMH

Comment: Could you please post it completely as code rather than image?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao http://collabedit.com/4hrp8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending input to input, try adding stock class to the div and append child inputs inside it like:

```
<div class="col-md-3 stock">
  {{ Form::label('stock', 'Stock') }}
  <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="stock" disabled>
</div>


 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='product_id']").on("change", function() {
      var productID = $(this).val();
      if(productID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url("admin/getProductInfo") }}/"+encodeURI(productID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $(".stock").empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $(".stock").append("<input type='text' class='form-control' value='"+value['stock']+"' name='stock' disabled>");
            });
        }
      }); //ajax
      }else{
        $(".stock").empty().append("<input type='text' value='' class='form-control' name='stock' disabled>");
      }
    });
  });
```

If data returns only one object, then try :

```
$('.stock').val(''); //Just to follow what OP has earlier and no need of else statement again
if(productID){
    //ajax stuff
    success:function(data) {
          //Clear the input's value

          if(data.length > 0){
             $(".stock input[type='text']").val(data[0].stock);
             //data[0].stock will be good if its parsed json
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: edited and removed stock class from appended input tags.

Comment: why is that? @GuruprasadRao

Comment: You just need to change the value of input with just `$(element).val(value['stock'])` and to clear you can just write `$(element).val('')`. But `append` is used to `append` the element within source specified. The approach you are using is a bad way of coding.

Comment: what if there are more than 1 value in data? then changing the same input will not help

Comment: well you have seen all my codes even my response codes please provide better way if you know so.

Comment: @sanatsathyan there is no other data, it will get info of chosen product, only 1 product data will return at the time.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao is this okay?? you are welcome to edit if there is any problem with the code.

Comment: @sanatsathyan That's what it should have been.. I've added my points though. +1.. :)

Comment: @sanatsathyan I tried it, it return value i need but output is empty `<input value="" class="form-control" name="stock" disabled="" type="text">`

Comment: @mafortis Just preload your success data into some variable to parse it.. For ex ... `var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);` and then use `parsedData[0].stock`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao you talk about something `parsedData ` that I have no idea what it is :)

Comment: Usually, you are supposed to parse `json` value coming from server and `JSON.parse(data);` does that job. I just termed it as `parsedData` that's it.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i tried your edit, everything disappeared after i select product http://collabedit.com/byscu

Comment: Ok.. console.log and see in browser console if it is coming inside `success` callback?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes it does